# Don't understand why autoload isn't working

Tags: php

So here's my autoload -

```
function __autoload($classname){
  include $classname.'.php';
}
```

I also tried using DOCROOT just in case....

```
function __autoload($classname){
  define('DOCROOT', dirname(__FILE__));
  include DOCROOT.'/'.$classname.'.php';
}
```

But when it comes across the PatentAssignment class, it says that it can't find the definition for the class...

Yet if I have an

```
include 'PatentAssignment.php';
```

in the constructor for the class that will use it, everything works fine.  Not sure what is going on.  In fact, it's not even calling autoload, just goes and gets confused about what to do.

Comment: So on every call you're defining a constant?

Comment: There's not a lot of information here... where is the __autoload function? is the file it is specified in included by the file trying to instantiate the object? is the file in the same directory as your class file?

Comment: extending on zerkms' commment: why not just use `include __DIR__ . '/' . $classname . '.php';`

Comment: Are you sure your __autoload() function is included before initiating the PatentAssignment class?

Comment: I mean I know I shouldn't be defining it, just did it because I was confused what was wrong.  And the __autoload is in the class, just a function in it.  Files are in the same directory as class file, which is why a straight up include works fine and everything runs.

Comment: I guess you are familiar with: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php  ? Whats your PHP version?

Comment: @Johan __autoload() is the first function defined in the class.

Comment: You should not define `__autoload()` inside any class file.

Comment: @genocide69 Whatever the latest version is, just updated it this week actually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`__autoload()` is not supposed to be a member method of a class - it is supposed to be a standalone function in the global namespace.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php

Comment: Well, that explains everything haha.

Answer (score 1):

What does the constructor look like (with the include)?
Put the autoload code before all class definition, best at top of the initializing php file.
Try debugging:

```
function __autoload($classname) {
  echo 'looking for ' . $classname . ' in ' . getcwd();
  include $classname.'.php';
}
```

1. http://php.net/manual/en/function.getcwd.php

Get the current working directory. Are all your files in the same folder?

1. http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload.php

Use spl_autoload instead:

```
  spl_autoload_register(function ($class) {
     include($class . '.php');
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    spl_autoload_register(function($class) {
    //your function here
    return class_exists($class, false);
   });
```